# Getting every day steps of month from parse in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, healthkit

```
- (void)didReceiveSteps:{        
    // Setting up time as Midnight
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:now];
    [components setHour:00];
    NSDate *today00am = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];

    NSLog(@" Current Midnight%@", today00am);

    // Getting First Day Of the month
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *firstDay = [gregorian components:(NSCalendarUnitEra | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth) fromDate:today];
    firstDay.day = 1;

    NSDate *dayOneInCurrentMonth = [gregorian dateFromComponents:firstDay];

    NSLog(@" First Day of The Month%@", dayOneInCurrentMonth);        

    NSDate *curDate = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar* ccalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents* comps = [ccalendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:curDate]; // Get necessary date components

    // set last of month
    [comps setMonth:[comps month]+1];
    [comps setDay:0];
    NSDate *tDateMonth = [ccalendar dateFromComponents:comps];
    NSLog(@"Last Day of the Month%@", tDateMonth);

    //Query Database
    // I get current Date steps from midnight through this query

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Stepss"];
    [query whereKey:@"ID" equalTo:deviceid];

    [query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

    [query whereKey:@"collectAt" greaterThan:today00am];

    [query selectKeys:@[@"steps"]];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            self.dailyStepsList = [objects valueForKey:@"steps"];

            NSNumber *sum = [_dailyStepsList valueForKeyPath: @"@sum.self"];
            sumSteps = [sum integerValue];
            NSLog(@"sum of steps is%lu" , sumSteps + step);
            NSLog(@"The Total Steps are%@",sum);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
```

I create a query that returns the data from start of the month till the end of the month. The data comes in hours for example
1.11.2016 01:00:00 60steps
1.11.2016 02:00:00 0steps
1.11.2016 03:00:00 90steps
1.11.2016 05:00:00 80steps
and so on till
30.11.2016 00:00:00 40 steps
The objective is to create bar chart of every day data separately.
For Example one bar for 1.11.2016, one bar for 2.11.2016 till 30.11.2016.
The day bar contains addition of all the steps of same day.

Comment: Try rereading this question from the perspective of another SO user.  How can someone possibly help without understanding the data model?

Comment: Now i have define the question more clearly